# ParallelSubmit does not trigger computations

Tags: parallelization

I am having some problems with parallel computations. I'm afraid it may be a "known issue" but I haven't found any solution.

In general, my script looks like this ("prepare" and "process" are my own functions, of course):

```
LaunchKernels[];
Needs["MyTools`"]; (* contains my "process" function *)
ParallelNeeds["MyTools`"]; (* all parallel kernels get it, too *)
output = {};
Do[input = prepare[i]; (* "input" is just a list of some matrices *)
   AppendTo[output, ParallelSubmit[{i, input}, {i, process[input]}]],
   {i, 1, 1000000}]; (* several hundred thousands to a million *)
WaitAll[output];
```

The problem is that the `Do` loop takes a very long time (10 to 20 hours or so) during which no single available "parallel kernel" is used (i.e. the `ParallelSubmit` calls do not "spawn" any calculations and first the `WaitAll` call triggers "parallel computations").

So, I thought that I could use:

```
LaunchKernels[];
Needs["MyTools`"]; (* contains my "process" function *)
ParallelNeeds["MyTools`"]; (* all parallel kernels get it, too *)
output = {};
WaitAll[
  Do[input = prepare[i]; (* "input" is just a list of some matrices *)
     AppendTo[output, ParallelSubmit[{i, input}, {i, process[input]}]],
     {i, 1, 1000000}]]; (* several hundred thousands to a million *)
```

Unfortunately, `ParallelSubmit` still does not trigger an immediate start of "parallel computations".

So, I am looking for a way to start "parallel computations" from inside of the `Do` loop and then wait for the completion of all "spawned" cases after the loop finishes.

Could you, please, advice me how to improve it. Thanks in advance.

**Update (2019.08.14)**: No matter what I tried, I had not been able to convince `ParallelSubmit` to immediately start ("submitted") calculations.
Then, Mathematica ran amok when I tried (it increasingly started to acquire tens of GB RAM for each running kernel and, at any moment, only two kernels were really using CPU):

```
output = {}; SetSharedVariable[output];
ParallelDo[input = prepare[i]; AppendTo[output, {i, process[input]}],
  {i, 1, 1000000}];
```

However, I was able to solve my problem by using `ParallelTable` (all available "parallel kernels" are used immediately). I realize that this is not a "general purpose" solution but, it may help someone so, I show it here:

```
output = ParallelTable[input = prepare[i]; {i, process[input]},
  {i, 1, 1000000}, Method -> "FinestGrained"];
```

Comment: One should distribute the definitions of all the related functions to all the subkernals by using DistributeDefinitions, and use ParallelSubmit[{x1___},expr] to substitute the current values of the x1.. into expr before submitting it for evaluation.

Comment: I would like to resurrect this question, because I am having a very similar problem in `Mathematica 13.2.1`.